# Checking out branch from origin

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have master and dev branches in origin in source tree, and I can't fetch them to local branches.

On the local machine these branches already exist - both master and dev - locally.

Trying to check out a branch from origin to local gives me the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree checkout -b dev --track origin/dev 
fatal: A branch named 'dev' already exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Rename your local branches out of the way, or delete them.

Comment: Now I am able to do the checkout, new local branch was created, but I still don't see this local branch in source tree.

Comment: Are you not seeing the commits? Then you need a git pull as Makoto says. It will fetch the remote commits to your local repo.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've locally created the branch, all you'd need to do is pull from it instead of checking it out again.

Use `git checkout <branch> && git pull` to accomplish this.